# Using criteria as sub query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

```
"select nation,count(Cid) 
     from Consumer 
         where Cid in(
             select user_id from user 
                 where merchant_id='"+Mid +"') 
         and nation='"+"ind"+"' 
     group by (nation)";
```

This is the  query, I don't know how to write sub query using criteria....if any one can convert above query into criteria, will be more helpful.

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail, also adding the schema of your tables would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this query:

```
DetachedCriteria userSubquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class, "u")
    .add(Property.forName("u.merchant_id").eq("Mid"))
    .add(Property.forName("u.nation").eq("ind"))
    .setProjection( Projections.property("u.user_id") );

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("nation"))
    .add(Projections.rowCount());

Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Consumer.class, "c")
    .add( Subqueries.propertyIn("c.cid", userSubquery) )
    .setProjection(projectionList);
List results = query.list();
```